# Three dimension array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to build a 3 dimension array with the following code :

```
while ($Inf = $queryPrep->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
 $cie_Names = array(
    $Inf->dp_id=>array(
    'name'=> $Inf->dp_desc, 
    'enabled'=>$Inf->dp_enabled));
}
```

Unfortunatly, this code was only returning the last record, so I chaged for :

```
$cie_Names = array();
while ($Inf = $queryPrep->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
     $cie_Names = [$Inf->dp_id]=>array(
    'name'=> $Inf->dp_desc, 
       'enabled'=>$Inf->dp_enabled);
}
```

But now I'm getting a error.

I'll need to call my array later this way :

```
foreach ($depts as $ID => $DeptDetail) {
   $optlist .= '<option value=' . $ID . '>' . $DeptDetail['name'] . $DeptDetail['enabled'] . '</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add a new element to an array by assigning to `arrayName[]`:

```
while ($Inf = $queryPrep->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    $cie_Names[] = array(
        $Inf->dp_id=>array(
            'name'=> $Inf->dp_desc, 
            'enabled'=>$Inf->dp_enabled
        )
    );
}
```

However, this seems like a poor array layout -- each element of the `cie_Names` array will be an associative array with a different key; accessing them will be difficult because you won't know how the keys map to array indexes, you'll have to do a loop to find anything. What would probably be more useful is:

```
while ($Inf = $queryPrep->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    $cie_Names[$Inf->dp_id] = array(
        'name'=> $Inf->dp_desc, 
        'enabled'=>$Inf->dp_enabled
    );
}
```

The keys of the `cie_Names` array will then by the `dp_id` values.

Comment: Thank You, it work, I changed for :  $cie_Names[$Inf->dp_id] =array('name'=> $Inf->dp_desc,'enabled'=>$Inf->dp_enabled);  // By adding the "ID" in at [], it solve my problem!